# Having difficulty adding items to shopping cart - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I have my `Cart` model as below

```
class Cart {
  String description;
  double unitCost;
  double amount;
  int quantity;
  String color;
  String imageURl;

  Cart({
    this.description,
    this.unitCost,
    this.amount,
    this.color,
    this.quantity,
    this.imageURl,
  });
}
```

And my `CartData` notifier class which has a `_cartList` with pre-loaded data as shown below:

```
class CartData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Cart> _cartItems = [
    Cart(
      imageURl:
          'https://s2.r29static.com/bin/entry/ebd/0,675,2000,1050/x,80/1929471/image.jpg',
      description: 'Nike Air Max',
      quantity: 3,
      unitCost: 6000,
    ),
    Cart(
      color: 'red',
      description: 'Nike Air Max',
      quantity: 3,
      unitCost: 3000,
    ),
    Cart(
      imageURl:
          'https://s2.r29static.com/bin/entry/ebd/0,675,2000,1050/x,80/1929471/image.jpg',
      description: 'Nike Air Max',
      quantity: 6,
      unitCost: 6000,
    ),
    Cart(
      color: 'purple',
      description: 'Nike Air Max',
      quantity: 2,
      unitCost: 1000,
    ),
    Cart(
      color: 'purple',
      description: 'Nike Air Max',
      quantity: 2,
      unitCost: 2000,
    ),
  ];

  UnmodifiableListView<Cart> get cartItems {
    return UnmodifiableListView(_cartItems);
  }

  int get cartItemsCount {
    return _cartItems.length;
  }

  void addItemToCart(
    String color,
    double unitCost,
    String description,
    String imageURL,
    int quantity,
  ) {    
    _cartItems.insert(
      0,
      Cart(
        color: color,
        unitCost: unitCost,
        description: description,
        imageURl: imageURL,
        quantity: quantity,
      ),
    );

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void getTotalSum(Cart cart) {}

  double getAmount(int qty, double unitCost) {
    return qty * unitCost;
  }

  void upDateCartItem(Cart cartItem, bool isIncrementing) {
    if (isIncrementing == true) {
      cartItem.quantity++;
      print(
          'Cart item purchase quantity is: ${cartItem.quantity}, after incrementing from updateCartItem');
    } else {
      if (cartItem.quantity >= 1) {
        cartItem.quantity--;
        print(
            'Cart item purchase quantity is: ${cartItem.quantity} after decrementing from updateCartItem');
      }
      if (cartItem.quantity == 0) {
        deleteItemFromCart(cartItem);
      }
      print(cartItem.quantity);
    }

    cartItem.amount = cartItem.quantity * cartItem.unitCost;
    print('Cart Item amount is: ${cartItem.amount} from updateCartItem');

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteItemFromCart(Cart cartItem) {
    _cartItems.remove(cartItem);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I want to be able to add items on the fly to my existing list of Cart Items using my `addItemToCart()` method, and display them immediately on my shopping cart page.

In my shopping screen, I have a few declarations as below:

```
  String defaultDescription = 'add description';
  String paymentDescription = 'add description';
  String amount = '0';
  int cartTotal = 0;
```

However, I'm unable to add item(s) to cart from my shopping screen when I call the addItemToCart method as below:

```
 _addToCart() {
    if (amount == '' || amount == '0') {
      print('add an amount');
      _showToast(this.context, 'amount');
    } else if (paymentDescription == defaultDescription) {
      print('please enter a valid description to proceed');
      _showToast(this.context, 'payment description');
    } else {
      print(amount);
      print(paymentDescription);
      //do something like add to cart
      CartData cartData = Provider.of<CartData>(context, listen: false);

      cartData.addItemToCart(
        null,
        double.parse(output),
        paymentDescription,
        null,
        1,
      );
    }  
    setState(() {
      paymentDescription = defaultDescription;
      amount = '0';
    });
 }
```

Here's my checkout screen that displays the cart Items:

```
class CheckoutScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'checkout_screen';

  @override
  _CheckoutScreenState createState() => _CheckoutScreenState();
}

class _CheckoutScreenState extends State<CheckoutScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    CustomerNotifier customerNotifier =
        Provider.of<CustomerNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    customerNotifier.getCustomers(customerNotifier);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => CartData(),
          child: Consumer<CartData>(
            builder: (context, cartData, child) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                          color: Colors.black26,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Shopping cart',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 21.0,
                          color: Colors.black26,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 16,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Customer drop down',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: kRegularTextStyle,
                          maxLines: 2,
                          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                          softWrap: true,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                          color: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 225,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 8.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: cartData.cartItems.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final cartItem = cartData.cartItems[index];

                          return cartData.cartItems.isEmpty
                              ? Container(
                                  child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Text('Your cart is empty')))
                              : Container(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: 80.0,
                                          height: 70.0,
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: cartItem.imageURl == null
                                                ? Container(
                                                    padding:
                                                        EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Color((math.Random()
                                                                      .nextDouble() *
                                                                  0xFFFFFF)
                                                              .toInt())
                                                          .withOpacity(1.0),
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                              20.0),
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                : Container(
                                                    padding:
                                                        EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                        image: NetworkImage(
                                                            cartItem.imageURl),
                                                      ),
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                              20.0),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                                      Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                            width: 100.0,
                                            child: Text(
                                              cartItem.description,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                          Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              GestureDetector(
                                                child: Container(
                                                  width: 20.0,
                                                  height: 20.0,
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadiusDirectional
                                                            .circular(4.0),
                                                  ),
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.remove,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    size: 15.0,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  cartData.upDateCartItem(
                                                      cartItem, false);
                                                },
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                        horizontal: 15.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  '${cartItem.quantity}',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.bold,
                                                      fontSize: 15.0),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              GestureDetector(
                                                child: Container(
                                                  width: 20.0,
                                                  height: 20.0,
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color:
                                                        kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadiusDirectional
                                                            .circular(4.0),
                                                  ),
                                                  child: Icon(
                                                    Icons.add,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    size: 15.0,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  cartData.upDateCartItem(
                                                      cartItem, true);
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      // Spacer(),
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          '${cartData.getAmount(cartItem.quantity, cartItem.unitCost)}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 15.0),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.delete_forever,
                                            size: 25.0,
                                            color: kThemeStyleButtonFillColour,
                                          ),
                                          onTap: () => cartData
                                              .deleteItemFromCart(cartItem),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: What do you mean you're unable to add item? Items added but widget not updated to show new item? Items not being added to the list?

Comment: Yes. The widget is not updating the new item so I'm unsure if it adds or not.

Comment: So you should put the code of your widgets

Comment: I've posted my shopping cart screen code. Wondering if you saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling your `addItemToCart()` should rebuild the children inside `Consumer<CartData>()` because of `notifyListeners()`. This should help you give some clue on what's happening.

Add a `debugPrint('List length: ${cartData.cartItemsCount}')` inside the Consumer to check if `List _cartItems` changes after adding an item.